# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem Vs new Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Press ENTER to start...");
    Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Scheduling work...");
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        //ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
        new Thread(_ =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }).Start();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

According to the textbook C# 4.0 Unleashed by Bart De Smet (page 1466), using new Thread should mean using many more threads than if you use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem which is commented out in my code.
However I've tried both, and seen in Resource Monitor that with "new Thread", there are about 11 threads allocated, however when I use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem, there are about 50. 
Why am I getting the opposite outcome of what is mentioned in this book?

Also why if you increase the sleep time, do you get many more threads allocated when using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem?

Comment: You are not creating any threads with your code. You are missing `Thread.Start` call.

Comment: Ah I see, you update the code, could you please repeat your testing now and also update the observed results?

Comment: With new Thread(_ =>, it stays around about 160 (+/- 10) for a couple of seconds, then drops down to 12 and stays there.

With ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>, it started at 20 and incremented every second up until 54 which it remained at for a few seconds, then it dropped down to 11 and stayed there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new Thread()` just creates a Thread object; you forgot to call `Start()` (which creates the actual thread that you see in resource monitor).

Also, if you are looking at the number of threads after the sleep has completed, you won't see any of the `new Thread`s as they have already exited.
On the other hand, the `ThreadPool` keeps threads around for some time so it can reuse them, so in that case you can still see the threads even after the sleep has completed.

With `new Thread()`, you might be seeing the number staying around 160 because it took one second to start that many threads, so by the time the 161st thread is started, the first thread is already finished. You should see a higher number of threads if you increase the sleep time.

As for the `ThreadPool`, it is designed to use as few threads as possible while also keeping the CPU busy. Ideally, the number of busy threads is equal to the number of CPU cores. However, if the pool detects that its threads are currently not using the CPU (sleeping, or waiting for another thread), it starts up more threads (at a rate of 1/second, up to some maximum) to keep the CPU busy.

Comment: Why is it, when I use the .Start() method, Resource Monitor shows the application using about 150 threads, and then a few seconds later it goes down to 11 threads and stays constant on 11?